# Find the integral: $\int{\frac{6x^4-5x^3+4x^2}{2x^2-x+1}}dx$

Tags: integration

I'm reading *Differential and Integral Calculus* by Piskunov, and have read up to integration using substitution. I've learned how to solve integrals of the form:
$$\int{\dfrac{Ax+B}{ax^2+bx+c}}dx$$
The integrals of the above form are solved by completing the square in the denominator, and decomposing the fraction into a sum such that the first fraction of the sum is of the form:
$$\int{\dfrac{2ax+b}{ax^2+bx+c}}dx$$
and the second fraction in the sum is of the form:
$$k\int{\dfrac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}}dx$$
By substituion, the above two terms are readily integrable.

I tried applying similar techniques to the following integral:
$$\int{\dfrac{6x^4-5x^3+4x^2}{2x^2-x+1}}dx$$
But have not been able to simplify them enough. The numerator is always two degrees higher than the denominator, and the $x^2$ term doesn't yield to the substitutions that worked in the simpler forms I wrote about above.

This is what I got after some simplification:
$$\dfrac{1}{4}\int{\dfrac{\left(3t^2+t-2\right)^2+71\left(t+1\right)^2}{\left(t^2+7\right)}}dt$$

$t$ is $4x-1$.

How can I solve the integral given in the question using only integration by substitution? In particular, can't use integration by parts.

Comment: Perform the long division first to arrive to something you knwo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$6x^4-5x^3+4x^2=(3x^2-x)(2x^2-x+1)+x$$
So $$\int \frac {6x^4-5x^3+4x^2}{2x^2-x+1} dx =\int (3x^2-x)dx+\int \frac {x}{2x^2-x+1} dx$$
I think you can do it now, using the techniques you mention in the question.